# How to change visibility of Back button in webview(Android)?

Tags: android, webview, payu

I want to remove that back button which is highlighted in below screenshot.

[image]

I am implemented Payubiz Payment gateway by using webview. I am not getting any way to remove that back button from webview.

Or else is there any way to set click event for that webview back button so that when i click on that back button I will directly come back to app.